# "Corrupted shell" after cryptdisks_start

Tags: 14.04, luks

I've been using luks encryption for USB backup drives for years with no problems, but now I have some strange behaviour. The difference is that here the whole system (except `/boot`) is on LVM over luks over a soft RAID.

Everything is OK with the encrypted LVM, but after doing a `cryptdisks_start` to unlock the backup drive (I added an entry in `/etc/crypttab` for it) everything I type (console or SSH session) is not displayed (including going to a new line after I type enter). I'm obliged to close the session (or both the root and user session if I did a `su -`) to get back to normal.

The drive is actually unlocked and I can use it. `cryptdisks_stop` works fine. If I remove the `/etc/crypttab` entry for the backup driver and unlock it with `cryptsetup luksOpen ...` it also works fine and the man page for cryptdisks_start says it's just a wrapper around cryptsetup that parses `/etc/crypttab`.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug that's only been fixed in the 14.10 version of cryptsetup, see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cryptsetup/+bug/1301086

I modified the setup to use a key file as the problem comes from askpass that is handling the interactive password.